# DELETE FROM mytable WHERE column LIKE '%word%' question

Tags: mysql

I have email addresses that I want to delete from my database. I would like to delete them by the domain name after the @ symbol.

Can I delete them like this?:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE column LIKE '%gmx.com%' OR column LIKE '%web.de%' 
OR column LIKE '%yandex.com%' OR column LIKE '%yahoo.com%'
```

Will it work?

Comment: use `like '% @domainmae'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no DB expert but it will not delete the email address but the entire record that contains any of domains mentioned in "column". If you want only to delete the email addresses then you should do something like

```
UPDATE mytable SET column = '' WHERE column LIKE '%gmx.com%' OR column LIKE '%web.de%' 
OR column LIKE '%yandex.com%' OR column LIKE '%yahoo.com%'
```

This will set only the email field to an empty string and defacto deleting the email address from the records in your WHERE clause and thus preserve the record.
Btw, I don't think you need the last % in '%yahoo.com%' if you want to get rid of everything after the @ and I think leaving out the last % will improve performance a bit.

Comment: Great idea. I may do that. Although I'd prefer to just delete the entries altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, if you can select them then you can delete them :)
I assume 'column' contain the email address so to your question, yes it will work but make sure if you only want to delete the value in that column or anything related to the value.

Comment: That's a very good tip. I am doing exactly that. I am testing it with SELECT to see if everything is working before I delete them.

Comment: @Jim James glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. Note that it will delete the row and not just the value in the column.

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this, but the person is right.